# Gmail REST API returns "Label color not allowed" on PATCH Label

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

i'm using the Gmail REST API to update a label's name.
Using the PATCH method:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/labels/id
```

I am passing only the Label name property.

If the label doesn't have color everything works fine, but if I have set some color from the Gmail client (from the predefined ones) I get the following error:

> "code": 400,
>     "message": "Label color #ff7537 is not on the allowed color palette"

This happens from my code and also using the sandbox from here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/patch?hl=bg

Update: 
Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a label from the API or from the UI:

[image]

2. Set a color to the label from the Gmail client
3. Try to update the name property of the same label from the API

Here is a screenshot from the sandbox:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> "code": 400, "message": "Label color #ff7537 is not on the allowed color palette"

As the error message mentions not all colors are valid the one you have sent is not.  (#ff7537)

If you check the documentation for [lables.resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels#resource) it states the valid ones

> color.backgroundColor  string  
>  The background color represented as hex string #RRGGBB (ex #000000). This field is required in order to set the color of a label. Only the following predefined set of color values are allowed: 
>   #000000, #434343, #666666, #999999, #cccccc, #efefef, #f3f3f3, #ffffff, #fb4c2f, #ffad47, #fad165, #16a766, #43d692, #4a86e8, #a479e2, #f691b3, #f6c5be, #ffe6c7, #fef1d1, #b9e4d0, #c6f3de, #c9daf8, #e4d7f5, #fcdee8, #efa093, #ffd6a2, #fce8b3, #89d3b2, #a0eac9, #a4c2f4, #d0bcf1, #fbc8d9, #e66550, #ffbc6b, #fcda83, #44b984, #68dfa9, #6d9eeb, #b694e8, #f7a7c0, #cc3a21, #eaa041, #f2c960, #149e60, #3dc789, #3c78d8, #8e63ce, #e07798, #ac2b16, #cf8933, #d5ae49, #0b804b, #2a9c68, #285bac, #653e9b, #b65775, #822111, #a46a21, #aa8831, #076239, #1a764d, #1c4587, #41236d, #83334c  writable
>
> color.textColor    string  
>  The text color of the label, represented as hex string. This field is required in order to set the color of a label. Only the following predefined set of color values are allowed: 
>   #000000, #434343, #666666, #999999, #cccccc, #efefef, #f3f3f3, #ffffff, #fb4c2f, #ffad47, #fad165, #16a766, #43d692, #4a86e8, #a479e2, #f691b3, #f6c5be, #ffe6c7, #fef1d1, #b9e4d0, #c6f3de, #c9daf8, #e4d7f5, #fcdee8, #efa093, #ffd6a2, #fce8b3, #89d3b2, #a0eac9, #a4c2f4, #d0bcf1, #fbc8d9, #e66550, #ffbc6b, #fcda83, #44b984, #68dfa9, #6d9eeb, #b694e8, #f7a7c0, #cc3a21, #eaa041, #f2c960, #149e60, #3dc789, #3c78d8, #8e63ce, #e07798, #ac2b16, #cf8933, #d5ae49, #0b804b, #2a9c68, #285bac, #653e9b, #b65775, #822111, #a46a21, #aa8831, #076239, #1a764d, #1c4587, #41236d, #83334c

[image]

Comment: the problem is that i haven't sent any color, but only the name. The color i have set through the Gmail client from the predefined colors, so how is it not allowed?

Comment: if you check the error message you are sending a color.   Why not post the rest of your code so i can test it.

Comment: i have added a screenshot from the Sandbox

Comment: Put me in the user id instead of what ever you have there now.  This is working fine for me.   **Me** is a short cut for the current authenticated user it works in most of the Google discovery apis

Comment: You haven't set a color for the label that you are editing. If the label doesn't have color it works fine!

Comment: well the screen shot you have given doesnt set it either.

Comment: I just did an update setting the color and it works fine.  New picture updated

Comment: i have added exact steps to reproduce, because i think you misunderstood something. Thank you for trying to help out!

Comment: Thats exactly what i did.  Have you tried this directly with the API and not with the Try me.  There could be a bug in that.   Or did you put an invalid color when you created the label?  In which case updating it to a valid color will probably help

Comment: In the API I use the short version me. I also tried the same in the Sandbox and still the same result. This is happening not only for my account but for other users too.

Comment: Send in a bug report but as its not something that can be recreated by anything other then your account i think its going to be hard to find https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191602%2B  I have done your steps and its working fine for me.  have you tried with a diffrent label and delete that label.   Assuming you are using the new gmail client it could also be a bug in that.

Comment: I have pinged Google but I dont actually have any contacts on that team going to have to wait to see if it gets forwarded on to someone who feels like looking into it.